# Motivation for designing libraries to be non-thread safe

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety

There are many libraries and APIs (e.g. [Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/threads-reentrancy.html#notes-on-qt-classes)) that seem to be intentionally designed to be non-thread safe. What is the motivation for such a design?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easier. Its really difficult to make a non trivial library thread safe without loosing

- simplicity
- scalability
- speed
- stability
- sanity

Since many developers value these things pretty high they often decide to not care about multi threading.

For GUI libraries sanity seems to be a major concern, since you get into really complex situations when you don't stick to a single thread for your GUI code.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the techniques used to ensure thread safety incur a performance penalty - if the likely use-cases for a library do not require thread-safety then omitting it can be a reasonable design choice.

Making a library non-thread safe does not preclude its use in a multi-threaded application, it just means that the user of the library must implement the thread safety themselves (usually by wrapping calls to the library in a thread-safe wrapper). By writing a library without thread-safety built in, the author allows does not force users who do not need thread-safety to suffer the associated performance penalty.